# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid'). Trying to get the currentUser.uid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not sure why I can't get the `currentUser.uid` using realtime database. This code causing me an error that tells that the property of user is `null`. I don't know if I'm missing something. Everything such as database and auth is imported properly.

[image]

[image]

Please explain to me what's happening.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

The `auth.currentUser.uid` is not a dependency of the `useEffect`. This means that a change in this Value will never trigger the `useEffect`.

One thing about `useEffect` is that it will not just trigger on dependency update but also on component mount. This means it will fire before your auth state has been set.

You should set `auth.currentUser?.uid` as a dependency and also check currentUser is valid in the `useEffect`.

Comment: still doesn't get the uid I've try to changed my code into this

`code
`

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    if(auth.currentUser) {
      const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
      const userRef = ref(db, "users/" + userId);
  
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const snapshot = await userRef.once("value");
          const data = snapshot.val();
          setFirstName(data.firstName);
          setLastName(data.lastName);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
  
      fetchData();
    } else {
      console.log("No user is signed in");
    }
  }, [auth.currentUser?.uid]);

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of the wider component and any other relevant code so we have more of a context on whats happening.